# Abort if tenant not found - Laravel

Tags: laravel, subdomain, multi-tenant

I am using **tenancyforlaravel** package and all are working fine.
When I hit the tenant does not exist in my app then I get an error

```
Tenant could not be identified on domain app.localhost
```

how can show an abort message here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better approach the package provides.

In `TenancyServiceProvider` add this in the boot method:

If you are using `TenancyByDomain` Middleware, use `$onFail` property, or you may change the Middleware class if you are not using `InitializeTenancyByDomain` to the targeted middleware.

```
\Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain::$onFail = function ($exception, $request, $next) {
    return redirect('https://my-central-domain.com/');
};
```

Head to this docs page for more info:
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/tenant-identification/#subdomain-identification